# How to generate thumbnail from PDF upload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-controller

I am trying to generate a thumbnail of the PDF I upload in laravel the thumbnail should be the first page of the PDF. Right now I am manually uploading an image to make the thumbnail like this:

```
if (request()->has('pdf')) {
            $pdfuploaded = request()->file('pdf');
            $pdfname = $request->book_name . time() . '.' . $pdfuploaded->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $pdfpath = public_path('/uploads/pdf');
            $pdfuploaded->move($pdfpath, $pdfname);
            $book->book_file = '/uploads/pdf/' . $pdfname;
            $pdf = $book->book_file;
        }

if (request()->has('cover')) {
            $coveruploaded = request()->file('cover');
            $covername = $request->book_name . time() . '.' . $coveruploaded->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $coverpath = public_path('/uploads/cover');
            $coveruploaded->move($coverpath, $covername);
            $book->card_image = '/uploads/cover/' . $covername;
            
        }
```

This can be tedious while entering many data I want to generate thumbnail automatically. I searched many answers but I am not able to find laravel specific. I tried to use ImageMagic and Ghost script but I couldn't find a solution and proper role to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't comment yet!
You can use [spatie/pdf-to-image](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image) to parse the first page as image when file is uploaded and store it in your storage and save the link in your database.

First you need to have `php-imagick` and `ghostscript` installed and configured. For issues with `ghostscript` installation you can refer [this](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image#issues-regarding-ghostscript). Then add the package `composer require spatie/pdf-to-image`.

As per your code sample:

```php
if (request()->has('pdf')) {
  $pdfuploaded = request()->file('pdf');
  $pdfname = $request->book_name . time() . '.' . $pdfuploaded->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $pdfpath = public_path('/uploads/pdf');
  $pdfuploaded->move($pdfpath, $pdfname);
  $book->book_file = '/uploads/pdf/' . $pdfname;
  $pdf = $book->book_file;

  $pdfO = new Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf($pdfpath . '/' . $pdfname);
  $thumbnailPath = public_path('/uploads/thumbnails');
  $thumbnail = $pdfO->setPage(1)
    ->setOutputFormat('png')
    ->saveImage($thumbnailPath . '/' . 'YourFileName.png');
  // This is where you save the cover path to your database.
}
```

Comment: Yes I came across this too but I got an error. Can you edit and wite a proper answer with code please it will help me to understand. Thanks.